# Handling dynamically generated elements in selenium webdriver via C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to automate testing of a webpage that contains a list of items.

It's a button "Create" in Google Drive with expanding elements.
I have used XPath locator to find button "Create"(`driver.FindElement(By.XPath(""))`, but I don't know how to get access to the expanded elements and click on them by using C# and webdriver.

Here is the code below. Help me, please.

```
 `<div tabindex="0" class="j-Ta-pb f-e f-e-dg a-Da-e" role="button" aria-label="Создать" style="-moz-user-select: none;" guidedhelpid="new_menu_button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
<div class="j-Ta-pb f-e-og-aa">
<div class="j-Ta-pb f-e-qb-aa">
<div class="j-Ta-pb f-e-rf" aria-hidden="true">Создать</div>
<div class="j-Ta-pb f-e-Tc">&nbsp;</div></div></div></div>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should base on static part. Assuming j-Ta-pb is static/unchanged all the time, you could use this xpath

```
//div[contains(@class, 'j-Ta-pb')]
```

Comment: well, it works only for the main "Create" button, but I haven't found appropriate way to click 'New Folder' in this combobox

Comment: Please post the html code snipet of New Folder button

Comment: it's not a button it's an element in combobox I think. The code below is shown for "Create" button. When I click on "Create" button some part of the code below is changed to this:`<div class="j-Ta-pb f-e f-e-dg a-Da-e f-e-ea f-e-hb f-e-mb>` and another elements is added:`<aria-expaned="true", aria-active descendant='':4w", aria-owns=":4w"`      The main thing , that I can't even use normally firebug with it . It has changed rapidly

Comment: My problem is that I can't automate click on element "Folder" in combobox,that appears, after I automate action click on "Create" button